# How to check if an mov file has video

Tags: video, ffprobe

Is there an `ffprobe` command I can run to see if an `mov` file that I have is audio-only or contains video as well? I have various `mov` files, some of which are audio dubs and some of which are full videos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply running `ffprobe "FILEPATH"` should provide you with the information you want:

```
bash-3.2$ ffprobe "FILEPATH"
ffprobe version 2.7.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2015 the FFmpeg developers

...... [omitted]

Duration: 00:00:01.49, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 23473 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 23832 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  rotate          : 90
  creation_time   : 2013-02-09 01:42:20
  handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
  encoder         : H.264
Side data:
  displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 59 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-02-09 01:42:20
  handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
```

In the above example, you can see there are two streams, one of which is Video (`Stream #0:0(und): Video`) and the other is Audio (`Stream #0:1(und): Audio`).